# IntersectionDetail постоянно возвращает Intersect

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas

Когда я выполняю у `ellipse3.rendergeometry.IntersectionDetail(ellipse3.rendergeometry);` всегда выходит...

> 1. Entry
> 2. Entry
> 3. Intersect
> 4. Intersect
> 5. Intersect
> 6. Intersect
> 7. Intersect

и так бесконечно

Что может быть не так? [image: Структура]

@Stack Я вот сделал на одну фигуру, стало теперь появляться просто Empty. Начал делать на другую фигуру, вылазит error что "Не удается задать свойство объекта "", так как он находится в состоянии "только чтение".". Вот код :

```
private void Ellipse_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { 
    var ellipse = sender as Ellipse
    foreach (Ellipse tb in FindVisualChildren<Ellipse>(canvas))
    {
        var g = tb.RenderedGeometry;
        g.Transform = (Transform)tb.TransformToAncestor(canvas);
        var m = ellipse.RenderedGeometry;//Вот здесь вылазит ошибка
        m.Transform = (Transform)ellipse.TransformToAncestor(canvas);
        IntersectionDetail khg = m.FillContainsWithDetail(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ellipse3.rendergeometry.IntersectionDetail(ellipse3.rendergeometry)` - это не опечатка? Выглядит так, будто вы пересекаете `ellipse3` с самим собой.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, опечатка )))

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если фигуры расположены в Canvas, то сравнение надо проводить в координатах Canvas.

```
var g = shape.RenderedGeometry;
g.Transform = (Transform) shape.TransformToAncestor(canvas);
```

Также надо сделать для другой фигуры и после этого сравнивать их Geometry.

---

**UPDATE**

Работающий пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483495/196972)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]